# Python regular expressions for simple questions

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I wish to let the user ask a simple question, so I can extract a few standard elements from the string entered.

Examples of strings to be entered:

- Who is the director of The Dark Knight?
- What is the capital of China?
- Who is the president of USA?

As you can see sometimes it is "Who", sometimes it is "What". I'm most likely looking for the "|" operator. I'll need to extract two things from these strings. The word after "the" and before "of", as well as the word after "of".

For example:

1st sentence: I wish to extract `"director"` and place it in a variable called `Relation`, and extract `"The Dark Knight"` and place it in a variable called `Concept`.

Desired output:

```
RelationVar = "director"
ConceptVar = "The Dark Knight"
```

2nd sentence: I wish to extract **"capital"**, assign it to variable "Relation".....and extract **"China"** and place it in variable "Concept".

```
RelationVar = "capital"
ConceptVar = "China"
```

Any ideas on how to use the `re.match` function? or any other method?

Comment: Natural language parsing is not simple. You can use regex to split the sentence up into words, but that's about all you can do with it.

Comment: Are all questions of the form `<question-word> is the <relation> of <concept>?`

Comment: @Barmar yes all questions are in this form to keep it simple :)

Comment: In that case the regexp should be very simple, what have you tried and how did it fail?

Comment: @Barmar tbh I have not been able to try much, as i wasnt able to fully grasp the concept. Im watching the Google video on python regex now, to see if i can comprehend it. The part im stuck on is how to extract and assign it to a variable (hoping the video will explain that)

Comment: This sounds more suited to a custom made parser ( http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/ ) or natural language parser ( http://nltk.org/ ) than to a regex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct that you want to use `|` for who/what.  The rest of the regex is very simple, the group names are there for clarity but you could use `r"(?:Who|What) is the (.+) of (.+)[?]"` instead.

```
>>> r = r"(?:Who|What) is the (?P<RelationVar>.+) of (?P<ConceptVar>.+)[?]"
>>> l = ['Who is the director of The Dark Knight?', 'What is the capital of China?', 'Who is the president of USA?']
>>> [re.match(r, i).groupdict() for i in l]
[{'RelationVar': 'director', 'ConceptVar': 'The Dark Knight'}, {'RelationVar': 'capital', 'ConceptVar': 'China'}, {'RelationVar': 'president', 'ConceptVar': 'USA'}]
```

Change `(?:Who|What)` to `(Who|What)` if you also want to capture whether the question uses who or what.

Actually extracting the data and assigning it to variables is very simple:

```
>>> m = re.match(r, "What is the capital of China?")
>>> d = m.groupdict()
>>> relation_var = d["RelationVar"]
>>> concept_var = d["ConceptVar"]
>>> relation_var
'capital'
>>> concept_var
'China'
```

Comment: this is indeed what im after. Question: right now you have hard coded the questions into it as an example (obviously)...so now i will have an attempt at using user input to assign to variable "l". right?  Thanx :)

Comment: @RHK-S8 check out the `raw_input` function(or just `input` if you're using python 3) if you want to get user input.  Glad to help :)

Comment: BTW, does this mean in your example it is now assigned key/value pairs? As i dont see how they are assigned :( sorry for asking stupid questions.

Comment: ah didnt refresh page, my bad

Answer (score 1):

Here is the script, you can simply use | to optional match one inside the brackets.

This worked fine for me

```
import re
list = ['Who is the director of The Dark Knight?','What is the capital of China?','Who is the president of USA?']
for string in list:
    a = re.compile(r'(What|Who) is the (.+) of (.+)')
    nodes = a.findall(string);
    Relation = nodes[0][0]
    Concept = nodes[0][1]
    print Relation
    print Concept
    print '----'
```

Best Regards:)